# How to use image tag and source in django template language system

Tags: html, css, json, django, encode

I have a encoded 64 image in json which going to insert into django html template.

How should I translate this

```
<img src="R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp(Some 64 bit image);base64 />
```

into django template?

I have a body tag to receive the data and a style tag to put in css.

Comment: What's your problem ? Be more specific.

Comment: The problem is very clear. How to translate the typical html way of inserting image into django template system especially with the base64 keyword.

Comment: Alright if I understand what you wrote, you saved images with base64 datas and you'd like to show it from your view to template ?

Comment: The front end will send me image with base64 datas. I am going to render this image in pdf therefore I need to render it into html template before I can do so. I couldn't find any information related to base 64 encoding in django template documentation. I am trying not to save the image into a png file and use the html to retrieve the image from filepath. The best is to render it directly.

Comment: The front end will the base64 data to Django, since you receive an already decoded base64 why do you need to encode it if you don't want to save the data ? getting it back through the template inside `<img src="base64...">` should work fine ? How is your problem related to django and json, in the title what does language system refer to ?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755900/django-render-dynamic-image-in-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Data URI and it has following [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Syntax)

```
data:[<media type>][;base64],<data>
```